# Reduction to particular cases of a lemma

Tags: analysis

> **Lemma:Let $\phi(s)$ be a non-negative and non-decreasing function. Suposse that 
>   \begin{equation}
> \phi(r) \le C_1 \left[\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\alpha + \mu \right]\phi(R) + C_2 R^\beta]
> \end{equation}
>   for all $r\le R \le R_0$, with $C_1,\alpha,\beta$ positive constants. Then, for any $\sigma<\min\{\alpha,\beta\}$ there exists a constant $\mu_0 = \mu_0(C_1,\alpha,\beta,\sigma)$ such that if $\mu<\mu_0$, then for for all $r\le R\le R_0$ we have
>   \begin{equation}
> \phi(r)\le C_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\sigma \left[\phi(R) + C_2R^\sigma \right]
> \end{equation}
>   where $C_3=C_3(C_1,\sigma-\min\{\alpha,\beta\})$ is a positive constant. In turn, 
>   \begin{equation}
> \phi(r)\le C_4r^\sigma,
> \end{equation}
>   where $C_4=C_4(C_2,C_3,R_0,\phi,\sigma)$ is a positive constant.**

**proof:**
We can assume $\beta < \alpha$ and, in this case, it suffices to show the estimate for $\sigma = \beta. \cdots$

**Ask** I'd like to prove the  assertion in the first line of the proof above.
The lemma can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5264v1.pdf) on page 9 and a similar lemma can be found in [article,book](http://www.nd.edu/~qhan/2008-0728Weak%20Solutions-USTC.pdf) in the end on page 10.

Comment: There is no $\mu$ below the definition of $\mu_0$.

Comment: @vesszabo : this is not a problem as $\mu$ is already defined before $\mu_0$. In fact the lemma is later used in the paper with $\mu=0$, so that $\mu < \mu_0$ will hold.

Answer (score 0):

The first line says two things :

(1) We may assume $\beta < \alpha$ in (2.6)

and

(2) In this case, we may further assume that $\sigma=\beta$.

Note that (2.6) still holds if we replace $\alpha$ by a larger value $\alpha’ > \alpha$ , because

$$
\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\alpha \le \Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^{\alpha’}
$$

So we may enlarge $\alpha$ as we please, and in particular we can make it $> \beta$. This justifies (1).

(2.7) can be written as $\phi (r) \leq F(C_2,C_3,\sigma,r,R)$ where $F$ is the complicated function defined by

$$
F(C_2,C_3,\sigma,r,R)=C_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\sigma \left[\phi(R) + C_2R^\sigma \right]
$$

Suppose that we have shown the estimate (2.7) when $\sigma=\beta$, so that $\phi (r)  \leq F(C_2,C_3,\beta,r,R)$ for $r \leq R \leq R_0$. Now let

$$
C’_3={\sf max}\Bigg(C_3,C_3R^{\beta-\sigma}\Bigg)
$$

This is a positive constant, and we have for $r \leq R$,

$$
C_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\sigma \leq C_3 \leq C’_3 \ \ {\text{and}}  \ \ C_3r^{\beta-\sigma} \leq C_3R^{\beta-\sigma} \leq C’_3
$$

and hence,

$$
C_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\beta \phi (R) \leq C’_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\sigma \phi (R)
 \ \ {\text{and}}  \ \ C_2C_3 r^{\beta} \le C_2C’_3 r^{\sigma}
$$

Adding up, we deduce

$$
\phi (r) \le F(C_2,C_3,\beta,r,R) \le F(C_2,C’_3,\sigma,r,R)
$$

This justifies (2).

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But I need to say the following: in the first part I know that 
\begin{equation}
C_1\Bigr[ \Bigr(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigl)^\alpha + \mu \Bigl] ]+C_2 R^\beta \le C_1\Bigr[ \Bigr(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigl)^{\alpha´} + \mu \Bigl] +C_2 R^\beta
\end{equation}
What I guess strange is that, if I do this, then I always will get $\min \{\alpha, \beta\} = \beta$.

Comment: In the second part. I'm not convinced that
\begin{equation}
C_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\beta \phi (R) \leq C’_3\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{R}\Bigr)^\sigma \phi(R)
\end{equation}
because this is equivalent to $C_3r^{\beta-\sigma}\dfrac{1}{R^\beta} \le C`_3\dfrac{1}{R^\sigma}$. I know that $C_3r^{\beta-\sigma} \le C’_3 $ but $\dfrac{1}{R^\beta}$ can be greater  than $\dfrac{1}{R^\sigma}$ for $R, \beta, \sigma $ convenient. I will be waiting some commentary.